Antlr grammars that generate actual class inheritance
Need to know, is it possible to generate parsers, lexers, listeners, etc, by importing subset-grammars? I  see that the supergrammar subgrammar pattern is possible, but I'm not sure I see a true class hierarchy being formed in the generated code. Either in the hard classes, or the softer interfaces. can we emulate that, perhaps with key infrastructure classes slotted underneath the listeners, for starters? I've introduced such in listeners approaching this question, so I know at least "that" is possible. But not for a grammar B that kinda sorta derives inherits from a grammar A. Do not know that, but it would be highly useful to what I got going on right now.

The import in ANTLR4 works by combining a main grammar with imported grammars. It's like replacing rules by imported rules and there's no class hierarchy, neither in the grammars, nor the generated files.

After working with it for a bit, I learned, it can be emulated, to a point. Not in the generated parser code itself, although it helps if your rules and rule overrides are consistently named, and mine are pretty simple, so it is not a big deal. But with some design decisions cooperating with the rules and the listeners, you can introduce base classes, which more or less do that magic under the hood. It's not pretty but it kinda sorta gets the job done.
